# How to return multilple returns or query in laravel -- I'm new in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
 $transactionType = ['request','transfer'];
 $transactions = Transaction::where(function ($query) use 
($request) {
    if (in_array("request", $transactionType))) {
        return $query->where('transactionType', 'request');
    }
    if (in_array("transfer", $transactionType)) {
        return $query->where('transactionType', 'transfer');
    }
})->get();
```

I want it to return both **returns** as `$transaction` contain both element 'transfer' and 'request' but it is returning only `$query->where('transactionType', 'request');`

Comment: Hey Aman, are you trying to get records for both the transaction types together ?

Comment: yes buddy, but only when $transactionType array has both 'request' and 'transfer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for,

```
 $transactionType = ['request','transfer'];
 $transactions = Transaction::whereIn('transactionType', $transactionType)->get();
```

Comment: oh my god , I knew about whereIn clause in laravel, but I didn't think to use it.
Thankyou @groovy_guy, you're a time saver. Thankyou chellam sir